# How to print results in python for every year up to a requested year

Tags: python

I have a working code
I have a working code, which gives the correct answer, however I cant figure out how to get it to print the amount for each year (for example if i enter 5yrs it will only give the amounts for the fifth year. I want it to print year 1, 2, 3 ,4 and 5 (print results for every year up to the entered year)

```
InvestAmount = int(input("Enter the intial investment amount: "))
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years to invest: "))
Rate = float(input("Enter the intrest rate (as %): "))

TotalInterestEarned = 0
for i in range(Years):
    InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
    EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)


print("Starting Balance: $"+ str (InvestAmount))    
print("Ending balance: $"+str(EndingBal))
print("Total Interest Earned: $"+str(InterestEarned))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift your print statements to the for loop and print i as well

```
    for i in range(Years):
      InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
      EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)
      print("Starting Balance: for year " +(i+1)+"$"+str (InvestAmount))    
      print("Ending balance: for year" +(i+1)+"$"+str(EndingBal))
      print("Total Interest Earned: for year" +(i+1)
      +"$"+str(InterestEarned))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gonna help you

```
InvestAmount = int(input("Enter the intial investment amount: "))
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years to invest: "))
Rate = float(input("Enter the intrest rate (as %): "))

TotalInterestEarned = 0
for i in range(Years):
    InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
    EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)
    print(f"{i+1} year - Starting Balance: ${InvestAmount}")    
    print(f"{i+1} year - Ending balance: ${EndingBal}")
    print(f"{i+1} year - Total Interest Earned: ${InterestEarned}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your for loop like this:

```py
for i in range(Years):
    InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
    EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)
    print("Year" + i+1 + " Interest Earned: $" + InterestEarned)
    print("Year" + i+1 + " Balance: $" + EndingBal)
```

Comment: Now I get the error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Nvm I forgot to a str

Comment: It gives me the year now but the interest or amount doesn't change, its the same every year when it should be increasing?